# Capture image from Camera and send as a file to Restful Webservice

Tags: javascript

I want html/javascript code where I can capture the picture with my camera and submit it as a file to restful webservice.

Comment: Any code ? What have you try ? What have you search ?

Comment: I don't know how to do, but I know how not to do. I have tried this once with an HTTP rest server. Performances are very low and very dependent on the browser you use. You should better look for an RTP server.